# Android API>=23: How to ask ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION in right way?

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I am checking user permissions allowance on Android API >=23 using this way.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void requestPermissions() throws RuntimeException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1234); //TODO: MOVE TO CONST
    }
```

Problem is that snippet mentioned above displays separated intent without the possibility to Explain why the app needs permissions (see attached image please). So I am using the modal window for displaying explanation why the app needs permissions and when the user clicked on the O.K button, intent with permission request is displayed.

[image]

This is not user-friendly at all and I would like to do the same thing (permission check + allowance) in the standard permission requesting way for Android API >= 23 like on:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Is it possible please or is this permission unique with something and have to be processed only this way?

Many thanks for any advice.